# Nginx redirect path to different path

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to redirect urls with Ninx but i'm struggling to get it right:

`example.com/{dynamic1}/foo/bar/{dynamic2}` to `example.com/{dynamic1}/bar/{dynamic2}`

basically i'm trying to remove the `/foo/` portion of the url.

i've tried the following:

```
location ~* ^/(.*)/foo/bar/(.*)$ {
  return 302 ^/$1/bar/$2?$args;
}
```

and also:

```
location ~ ^/([^/]*)/foo/bar/(.*)$ {
  return 302 ^/$1/bar/$2?$args;
}
```

but this throws the error `414 Request-URI Too Large` and the url ends up being (shortened for clarity):

`dynamic1/cams/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/%5E/dynamic1/bar/dynamic2?`

What am I doing wrong?

Note that once i get this right i will replace 302 with 301.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have placed a caret at the beginning of the destination URL path that you appear to have intended to redirect to. This does not belong there, and it is why `%5E` shows up repeatedly.